# Is this modification of connexity necessary, or redundant in the definition of partial ordering?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, definition, relations, order-theory

My question pertains to [Fundamentals of Mathematics, Volume 1
Foundations of Mathematics: The Real Number System and Algebra, Edited by H. Behnke, F. Bachmann, K. Fladt, W. Süss and H. Kunle](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/fundamentals-mathematics-volume-1)  **Vol-1 A8.3 Special Properties of Relations**

The terms in use are defined as:
$$\begin{aligned}
\text{transitive:}&\ \forall_{x}\forall_{y}\forall_{z}\left(\left(x\mathrm{r}y\land y\mathrm{r}z\right)\implies x\mathrm{r}z\right)\\
\text{identitive:}&\ \forall_{x}\forall_{y}\left(\left(x\mathrm{r}y\land y\mathrm{r}x\right)\implies x=z\right)\\
\text{connex:}&\ \forall_{x}\forall_{y}\left(x\mathrm{r}y\lor y\mathrm{r}x\right)
\end{aligned}$$

The following statement seems to have a redundancy:

> Relations which are transitive, identitive and connex are called *orderings in the sense of $\le$* (example: $x\le y$). For *orderings in the sense of $<$* the requirements of indentitivity and connexity are replaced by $\forall_{x}\lnot x\mathrm{r}x$ and $\forall_{x}\forall_{y}\left(x\ne y\implies\left(x\mathrm{r}y\lor y\mathrm{r}x\right)\right).$

In particular, the condition $x\ne y$ seems to have already been given.  For if $x=y$ then $x\mathrm{r}y\iff x\mathrm{r}x\iff y\mathrm{r}x,$ which is precluded by $\forall_{x}\lnot x\mathrm{r}x$. Am I correct in this understanding?

Comment: Do you mean that, in your opinion, the definition of ordering in the sense of $<$ does not need to replace the "connex" condition? Is this your question?

Comment: yes.  That is the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary that in the definition of ordering in the sense of $<$, the connex property is replaced by the condition $\forall x \forall y (x \neq y \implies (x\,R\,y \lor y\, R\, x))$. Otherwise, there would not exist any ordering in the sense of $<$, because the connex property and the irreflexive property (i.e. $\forall x \, \lnot(x\,R\,x)$) are incompatible: if one of the two holds, the other is false.

Indeed, suppose that an ordering in the sense of $<$ is defined as a relation $R$ that is

1. transitive: $\forall x \forall y \forall z ((x\,R\,y \land y\,R\,z) \implies x\,R\,z)$
2. irreflexive: $\forall x \, \lnot (x\,R\,x)$
3. connex: $\forall x \forall y (x\,R\,y \lor y\, R\, x)$.

*Proposition*. In every non-empty set, there is no ordering in the sense of $<$.

*Proof*. By contradiction, suppose that $R$ is an ordering in the sense of $<$ on a non-empty set $S$. Let $z \in S$ (it exists because $S$ is not empty). By the connex property taking $x = y =z$, we have $z\,R\,z \lor z\,R\,z$, that is, $z\,R\,z$. But this is impossible because of the irreflexive property.$\qquad\square$

---

What is wrong in your reasoning? You claim that, because of irreflexivity, we already know that $x \neq y$ and so this hypothesis $x \neq y$ in the condition $\forall x \forall y (x \neq y \implies (x\,R\,y \lor y\, R\, x))$ is superfluous and can be dropped, since it always holds.

Wait! The convex property says that *for every* $x$ and $y$ in the set $S$ where the relation $R$ is defined, we have $x\,R\,y$ or $y\, R\, x$. By irreflexivity, this implies that $x \neq y$. But convexity is talking about *every* $x$ and $y$ in the set $S$, also when $x = y$. Summing up, irreflexivity and convexity together are saying that whenever you take whatsoever $x$ and $y$ in $S$, necessarily we have $x \neq y$; but this is absurd, because you can always choose $x = y$ in $S$.

To avoid this contradiction, in the definition of ordering in the sense of $<$, the hypothesis $x \neq y$ added to the convex condition is *not* redundant, but *necessary*.

Said differently, you are right when you say that if you assume irreflexivity and convexity, then

\begin{align}\tag{*}
\text{for every $x$ and $y$ we have $x \neq y$}
\end{align}
Your error is that you did not notice that $(*)$ is claiming something impossible, and hence irreflexivity and convexity cannot coexist: there is no relation that is both irreflexive and connex.

---

A terminological remark. The terminology used in your reference is quite unusual. Often, the "ordering in the sense of $\leq$" is called [total or linear (nonstrict) order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), the "ordering in the sense of $<$" is called total (or linear) strict order, the "connex" property is called total or linear or strong connnected, the "identitive" property is called antisymmetric.

Comment: I'm sorry; I read too much into your previous comment.  My contention is that the condition of irreflexivity already precludes the case of $x=y$.  So there is no need to restate $x\ne y$ in a modified connex definition.  That is to say $x=y$ means $x\mathrm{r}y$ is identical to $x\mathrm{r}x$, which irreflexivity forbids.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton - I insist that when you say "there is no need to restate $x \neq y$ in a modified connex condition", you are wrong. It is necessary to modify the connex property and require the hypothesis $x\neq y$ in it, exactly because of irreflexivity, to avoid a contradiction. See my edit.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton - Also, you are wrong when you say "irreflexivity already precludes the case of $x=y$", because it is only when you assume irreflexivity+connexity together that the case $x = y$ is precluded. Hence the contradiction stems from irreflexivity+connexity together.

Comment: Apparently this is similar to the idea of "orthogonal" axioms.  If instead of "properties of a relation", we say "axioms of a relation" and stipulate that these axioms must be orthogonal,  then your reasoning becomes more compelling.  I was thinking of the relation as a set of ordered pairs which satisfy all of the stated properties.  If I'm not mistaken, my method will produce the same set of pairs as that which you endorse.  So I'm still a bit unsure if my method is actually wrong.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton - I'm not sure to understand. What's the difference between a "property of a relation" and an "axiom of a relation"? What are "orthogonal axioms"? When you say that you think of "a relation as a set of ordered pairs which satisfy all of the stated properties", if the stated properties are the conjunction of transitivity, irreflexivity and connexity, then there is no such a relation; if instead you replace connexity with its weak form (adding the hypothesis $x \ne y$) then there are many examples of such a relation, e.g. the usual strict order on $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb R$.